# Partial screenshot with rectangle of selection c#

Tags: c#, selection, screenshot, partial

I'm trying to take a partial screenshot of the screen and put it in a picturebox. The user has to draw a rectangle and then i have to get the portion inside the rectangle.

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mRect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
    this.Invalidate();
}

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if( e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        mRect = new Rectangle(mRect.Left, mRect.Top, e.X - mRect.Left, e.Y - mRect.Top);
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}


protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{

    using(Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1))
    {
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, mRect);
    }
}
```

With this code i can draw a recangle, but i don't know how to do the screenshot. Maybe with the fonction CopyToScreen?

If someone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Make a borderless fullscreen window2 with tansparencykey (any color __but__ fuchsia) and let the user draw on it. then use a key to trigger the action: hide the window2,  grab a screenshot, draw the part you want into a bitmap, assign it the the picturebox.image, close the window2..done

Comment: As you can see in Rob's answer, the missing fuction is `CopyFromScreen`. If you have problems I can post a complete solution..

Comment: Yes i'm trying with the rob's solution, there is no error but it's not working! I'm a very begginer so i must have done something wrong but i can't see what!

Comment: TaW if you can post your complete solution it would be very kind of you! :)
Thanks :)

Comment: I just did. Note however that some parts are somewhat advanced; so don't simply copy it but study the code as well..! –

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code I use - it grabs the whole desktop

```
    public static Bitmap GetScreenAsBmp()
    {
        int min_x=0, max_x=0, min_y=0, max_y=0;
        foreach (Screen s in Screen.AllScreens)
        {
            min_x = System.Math.Min(min_x, s.Bounds.Left);
            max_x = System.Math.Max(max_x, s.Bounds.Right);
            min_y = System.Math.Min(min_y, s.Bounds.Top);
            max_y = System.Math.Max(max_y, s.Bounds.Bottom);
        }
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(max_x - min_x, max_y - min_y);
        Graphics dst_dc =  Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        dst_dc.CopyFromScreen(min_x, min_y, 0, 0, new Size(max_x - min_x, max_y - min_y));
        dst_dc.Dispose();
        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: I should say that MaxOf and MinOf return the largest and smallest of their arguments.

Comment: Actually you could/should use `Math.Max&Min()`

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete solution for the problem.

It is triggered by a `Button` and then:

- creates and styles a second `Form` which

  - is transparent without borders etc and fills the screen
  - has all events needed to draw a `Rectangle`
- copies the screen after the rectangle is drawn, i.e. after the `MouseUp`
- and copies the `Bitmap` into the Image of a `PictureBox` on the 1st Form.
- Finally it closes the 2nd form. During the screencopy process both windows are hidden, so you can grab the screen itself with all its content.

Note that many video overlays can't be captured this way!

Note that this code always captures from the 1st screen!

For best usability the users should somehow be informed that he is expected to draw the frame after the `Button` is pressed and the window has disappeared!

To use it simply add a `Button` and a `PictureBox` to your `Form`..

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
  }

  Form form2;
  Point MD = Point.Empty;
  Rectangle rect = Rectangle.Empty;

  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Hide();
     form2 = new Form();
     form2.BackColor = Color.Wheat;
     form2.TransparencyKey = form2.BackColor;
     form2.ControlBox = false;
     form2.MaximizeBox = false;
     form2.MinimizeBox = false;
     form2.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
     form2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
     form2.MouseDown += form2_MouseDown;
     form2.MouseMove += form2_MouseMove;
     form2.Paint += form2_Paint;
     form2.MouseUp += form2_MouseUp;

     form2.Show();
 }

 void form2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     MD = e.Location;
 }

 void form2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Button !=MouseButtons.Left) return;
     Point MM = e.Location;
     rect = new Rectangle(Math.Min(MD.X, MM.X), Math.Min(MD.Y, MM.Y),
                          Math.Abs(MD.X - MM.X), Math.Abs(MD.Y - MM.Y));
     form2.Invalidate();
 }

 void form2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
     e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rect);
 }

  void form2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
     form2.Hide();
     Screen scr = Screen.AllScreens[0];
     Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
     using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
     {
         G.CopyFromScreen(rect.Location, Point.Empty, rect.Size,
                          CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
         pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
     }
     form2.Close();
     Show();
  }

}
```